# Remove the first occurrence of close bracket ]

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

Using sublime text regex find and replace, how can I capture the first occurrence of a closing bracket **]**?

This regex works as expected and captures up to the first opening bracket:

`^([^\[]*)\[`

`你_ 你_ [`ni3] you (informal, as opposed to courteous 您[nin2])_

But this, for closing bracket, doesn't pick up anything:

`^([^\]]*)\]`

---

[image]

Comment: Could you give some examples of valid and invalid strings? Your last regex actually captures every string that doesnt begin with a "]" until it  finds a "]" - is that the expected behaviour? So if your string begins with a closing bracket, for example, it wont capture anything.

Comment: @VictorLiaFook so how can I be sure to only capture the first occurrence of `]`? I've tried `^(\S*)\]` as well to match any non whitespace character up until I find first occurrence of `]` but this doesn't capture anything either

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what does `\K` do? And what's the difference between `\A` and `^`? `\A` says "Matches at the start of the current string." while `^` "Matches the start of the string." - what's the difference here for my purposes?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this doesn't seem to work

Comment: The `\A([^]]*)\K]` selects the first `]` in my Sublime Text 3 (Build 3126) Search and Replace dialog. It works the same way as [here](https://regex101.com/r/YZ1Fjz/1). What are you doing?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew see edit above. I'm also on build 3126. Nothing is matched with that regex. And why don't I need to escape the `]` inside the `[ ]` brackets? Shouldn't it be `\A([^\]]*)\K]`

Comment: See http://imgur.com/F2cdm1z. You need to uncheck *Whole Word*
 option. You do not need to escape `]` outside a character class and when it is the first char inside a character class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot, the *Whole Word* option is enabled:

[image]

Thus, the `]` you match requires a word char after it and the first char should be a word char, too.

A possible solution for you use just disabling the option.

However, if you just need to select/highlight/replace/remove the first `]` in the file, you may use

```
\A[^]]*\K]
```

where:

- `\A` - matches the start of the document
- `[^]]*` - matches 0+ chars other than `]`
- `\K` - a match reset operator that omits the whole text matched so far
- `]` - matches a literal `]`.

You do not need to escape `]` outside a character class and when it is the first char inside a character class *in PCRE/Boost regex flavor*.

[image]

Note that **if you need to match the first `]` on each row**, you need to replace `\A` with the `^` (start of a line anchor) and add `\r\n` to the negated character class:

```
^[^]\r\n]*\K]
```

[image]

Comment: Wiktor this needs to be applied to a `n` rows with similar structure. Right now it's only matching one row

Comment: Replace `\A`  with `^` and add `\r\n` to the negated character class (`^[^]\r\n]*\K]`) if you need to match the first `]` *on each row*.